# How to prevent app.exe.config file in output directory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, app-config

I'm using VS2019, My project is a .net framework 4.8 c# winform, no `app.config` file in project, wrote `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>false</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>` in `.csproj/Project/PropertyGroup`. when build finished, the `xxx.exe.config` file generated in `bin` folder, I hate it, how to let it go?

file content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on your **Project Properties**-->**Build Events**--> type these under **Post-Build Event command line**:

```
del $(TargetDir)$(AssemblyName).exe.config
```

**Update**

change the **Build Action** of the `app.config` file to `Resource`.

The customer just deletes the `app.config` file.

Comment: The `exe.config` is a copy of app.config file under the condition of `None` or `Content` build action. If you do not want the above workaround, you could change the app.config file's Build Action to `Resource`. And It can break the copy operation from the root cause at the time of construction

Comment: But I already deleted `app.config` from project, so not copy reason, it's msbuild generate it i guess.

Comment: Sure. Deleting it is not a good choice. You could try my method and just change the Build Action of the app.config file to Resource. Sure. the `exe.config` is generated by `app.config` file through msbuild when it is `Content` or `None` Build Action.

Answer (score 5):

For SDK-style, executable projects targeting .NET Framework, it is possible to prevent the `xxx.exe.config` file from being generated by adding the following line to the first `<PropertyGroup>` of the project file:

```xml
<GenerateSupportedRuntime>False</GenerateSupportedRuntime>
```

**Bonus Info**
The file responsible for generating it is [Microsoft.NET.GenerateSupportedRuntime.targets](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/main/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/targets/Microsoft.NET.GenerateSupportedRuntime.targets).

Comment: Nice & Clean, better than delete, thx :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**
In some cases the application requires the config file in order for it to run. However, if you can delete it and it still runs, but you don't want it to automatically generate, you can do this:
**Right Click Project > Properties > Build Events** > Add this to **Post-build event command line**:

```
del $(TargetDir)$(AssemblyName).exe.config
```

This won't work in all cases though, since sometimes the application does require it in order for it to run.

**Solution 2**
You can get around this by turning the App.config file into a resource.
**Right Click App.config > Properties >** Change **Build Action** to **Resource** or **Embedded Resource**.
Either one *should* cause the config file to not be generated.